# missing return statement even method is having void return type

Tags: java

am writing a java program as below.

```
Void fun(int n){

for(int i=0;i<=n;i++){

fun(n-i);

}

System.out.println(“well done”);

}
```

I am getting error, missing return statement. I not used int or string method. It is void method na. why it asking return type, please help for this problem.

Comment: void (and Java) is case sensitive

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Void`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html) is a reference type.

`void` is a language primitive.

[You don't need a `return` statement when your return type is `void`.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.17)

Comment: ya, but what is the error am not getting.

Comment: @SurekhaS Capitalization matters. `Void` != `void`